# Is there any Url Spider component that I can reuse?

Tags: c#, .net, url, hyperlink, web-crawler

I'd like to build a spider tool using which I can run it against a website root url then it should find all the broken and healthy links (images, css, .aspx, .docs) by specifing the degree of parsing e.g. 2 levels.

Then at the end it should generate a map of the result either in Xml or in DataTables

Is there any ready third party or free tool that I can reuse in my .NET application?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Chilkat ASP.Net Spider component before. It allows you to specify the number of levels to crawl, and allows you to set up exclusions etc.

It won't generate a map for you automatically (or at least the version I worked with didn't), but logging the results to either a database or XML should be fairly easy. Details on the component can be found [here](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/spider.asp), and you can download the component for free from [here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_DotNet.asp)